# If an electron can't go faster than light, how is energy conserved here?

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics, speed-of-light, energy-conservation, acceleration

I came across a physics question recently about accelerating electrons with potential differences and it got me wondering.

Here is the question that brought the concept to mind.

[image: Physics Question]

**First off, imagine if the potential difference is actually 260kV and not 350V.**

Imagine that we put the electron there with our finger, so we are giving it energy which it stores as potential energy.

The amount of energy we give it is equal to $$W=\Delta V\cdot q_e$$

In theory, when the electron accelerates to the entrance of the deflecting plates, it should have gained all of the energy we put into it as kinetic energy.

$$1/2 \cdot m \cdot \rm v^2 = \Delta V \cdot q_e$$

$$1/2 \cdot 9.11\, \rm x \, 10^{-31} \cdot v^2 = 2.6 \, \rm x \, 10^5 V \cdot 1.6\, \rm x \, 10^{-19}\, \rm C $$

$$ \rm v \approx 3.02 \, \rm x \, 10^8 \, m/s$$

Therefore, if all of the potential energy stored in the electron was converted to kinetic energy, it should go faster than the speed of light. What would prevent this? And if this is prevented, how is the Law of Conservation of Energy Maintained?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short version is that you are using an incorrect expression for the energy of a particle in motion.

The correct, general expression for the kinetic energy of a particle of mass $m$ is $$ T = (\gamma - 1) m c^2 \,,$$
where $\gamma$ is the Lorentz factor
$$ \gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \left( \frac{v}{c} \right)^2 }} \,.$$

The version that you use, $T = \frac{1}{2}mv^2$ is only valid when $v \ll c$.